# how to show data present in a datagridview in a text-box?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

my question here is that how can i import the data from a record in (sql) datagridview in to respective textboxes. For example if i click on a record the entire record should be imported in to textboxes.

thanks

[enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/365005)

Comment: What GUI are you using ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: datagridview = winforms

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textbox1.Text=dataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value
```